# How can i document dictionary keys for a functions argument?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to figure out how can I provide type hints for a dictionary argument being passed to a function without using `Dict[str, str]` as that doesnt provide what the keys will be.

I have tried two approaches so far, one with using `typing_extensions` so that I can have compatibility with 3.6, and also with `pydantic`, but I cant get the hits to show.

Consider this example code:

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Some(TypedDict):
    """keya is some key"""
    keya: str
    """another_key is another key"""
    another_key: str

def some(a: Some) -> None:
    print(a.get('keya'))
    return None


some({'keya': 'key', 'another_key': 'nonething'})
```

[image]

As expected, the type hints for the `some` function shows the type `Some`, but not its keys.

What I am trying to accomplish is 2 things.

- Provide key hints when the function argument is a dict (most important)
- Generate documentation with sphinx so that the keys reflect in the documentation.

#### Edit

As on of the comments pointed out, I can accomplish this with `**kwargs` to some extent, but that is not the intention. Setting `**kwargs` does not give me type hints either.

Comment: This seems like you're asking for a fix for a problem that is entirely self-imposed. Why use a single dict argument if you really expect multiple specific arguments in it? Have you considered not passing the arguments as a dict, but as individual keyword arguments? Your callers could use `some(**some_dict)` if they already have the arguments packed up in a dictionary.

Comment: @Blckknght yes, you are right. I can easily go around this with `**kwargs`, but that is not the intention. The question is more around if this could be done, and if not, I understand.

Comment: @Blckknght just to clarify also, `**kwargs` does not give me the intended result of showing type hints to the user on what valid keys will be. My example is simplified in this post. If the function takes 10 arguments which are a mix of dict and lists and strs, then I cannot accomplish what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: The suggestion is not to use `**kwargs`, it's to use `keya, another_key` as direct arguments to the function. You can then pass in a dict with those keys with `some(**d)`.

Comment: You would use default values and `**kwargs` to handle missing or extra keys in the input, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case, it might actually be better to file a feature request/submit a pull request to your editor improving the quality of its type hinting. Similarly, with sphinx, you could submit a pull request that ensures that the docs either properly link to the definition of Some or include a more detailed description within the function signature itself.

After all, the problem you're facing is a limitation of your editor/sphinx, not with Python or type hints, and you might get better long-term results if you tackle the problem at the source.

You may also get better results if you use the "constructor" of `Some` instead of passing in a dict literal. At least for me, doing this gets me full key hints for `Some` when using PyCharm. Not sure if that'll also be the case for your editor:

```
some(Some(keya='key', another_key='nonething'))
```

Note that doing `Some(...)` will actually just return a plain old regular dict at runtime, so this shouldn't lead to any difference in behavior.

It could also be worth trying to do:

```
x: Some = {
    "keya": "key",
    "another_key": "nonething",
}
some(x)
```

...to see if your editor might give better hints with that form.

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat narrowed down to a possible solution using the following code. It meets most of the requirements:

- mypy type checks passes
- shows keys
- documentation also shows keys and types
- The main caviate to this solution is that mypy thinks the value is optional because of a default value so the solution is not quite complete.

Using the `validate_items` function, I can validate that the values are there. Please see the comments on the code snippet and offer suggestions.

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from typing import Union

class Some(TypedDict):
    keya: str
    another_key: str

def validate_items(v: dict) -> None:
    for key, value in v.items():
        assert isinstance(value,str), '{} is required'.format(key)
        # Would love to pull the type of a key from the Some class here or
        # would love to put the validation in the Some class itself


def some(a: Some={'keya': '', 'another_key': ''}) -> None:
    """[summary]

    Args:
        a (Some, optional): [description]. Defaults to {'keya': '', 'another_key': ''}.

    Returns:
        [type]: [description]
    """    
    validate_items(dict(a))
    print(a.get('keya'))
    return None
```

[image]

In the screenshot, I can see that mypy is complaining about the `None` value which is expected, and in the popup help, we can also see the keys that are required in the dictionary being passed along with the type that is being set to it.

The solution feels quite hacky, and would appreciate any corrections to make it more pythonic.